# Changing a boolean in a class file from the main latex file

Tags: document-classes, class-options, xifthen

I'm trying to change a boolean value located in a class file (`.cls`) from the main latex document (`.tex`). I've tried to set the boolean in the main latex file using `\setboolean{showwatermark}{true/false}`.

The class file `toad.cls` contains:

```
\ProvidesClass{toad}[2017/09/12 v 0.1 learning about variables]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[]{article}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newboolean{showwatermark}
\setboolean{showwatermark}{false}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{showwatermark}}{%
\newwatermark[allpages,color=black!20,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{IN REVIEW}}{}
```

The latex file contains:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{toad}
\setboolean{showwatermark}{true}
\begin{document}
Some text...
\end{document}
```

I have a feeling this is horrifically wrong. Would the better approach here be to define a `newcommand`?

Comment: The test in the class doesn't make sense. There is no interface to change the boolean before it is used. Or did you remove some parts of the class?

Comment: Why does the class provide its own boolean rather than using whatever interface `xwatermark` provides? What is the point of the boolean?

Comment: When the conditional is evaluated, the boolean is false. Later, you set the boolean to true, but no code evaluated later makes any use of that value. Hence, setting the boolean in the document is useless. Why not just pass `printwatermark` to the class so it is picked up by the package? `printwatermark=false` or `printwatermark` (`printwatermark=true`) can override whatever setting is default in the class. Provided the class processes the options, of course (which you're already doing).

Comment: Off-topic: `9pt` is not an option recognised by `article.cls`. It is equivalent to the default i.e. `10pt` as it will be ignored.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this is how I received the `.cls` file and one of the reason why I'm looking at boolean value setting to avoid manually editing the file.

Comment: @cfr the look of it would be `\documentclass[printwatermark=true]{toad}`? Then the `\newwatermark` command would not require the `ifthenelse` structure?

Comment: @coatless I'm not familiar with `xwatermark` so I only looked at the manual quickly but, yes, that would be the idea. The class file would just do whatever is specific to that class (e.g. define a specific watermark). It would let `xwatermark` handle the switching, which it already provides a user interface for. As written, the class will never produce a watermark as far as I can tell. Because the `\newwatermark` is never executed since the condition is always false. If you were given this class, don't use it. Whoever wrote it clearly doesn't know what they're doing and didn't test it at all.

Comment: @cfr, thanks for the insight. Would you like to post this as an answer? I will accept it.